# Determining corners and faces of polyhedron

Tags: optimization, solution-verification

I want to find the corners, faces and the dimension of the faces of a polyhedron. I would very much appreciate someone looking over my work, especially the part concerning the definitions of the faces.

The polyhedron $\mathcal{P}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ is defined by the inequalities:  $\quad x_1+x_2\geq 1,\quad x_1-x_2\geq 3$
This gives us matrix $A$ and vector $b$ with:
$A=\begin{pmatrix}  -1\quad -1\\-1\qquad1\\\end{pmatrix},\qquad b=\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\-3\end{pmatrix}\quad$ and $\quad Ax\leq b$
 $\mathcal{P}$  has one corner and to find it, we must see where the two inequalities intersect:
$1-x_1=-3+x_1\iff x_1=2 \implies x_2=-1$
Now to prove that $z:=(2,-1)^\text{T}$ really is a corner:

$\begin{pmatrix}  -1\quad -1\\-1\qquad1\\\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\-1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\-3\end{pmatrix}$
$\implies$ eq$(\{z\})=(1,2)\implies \text{rank}(A_\text{eq(z)})=\text{rank}\begin{pmatrix}  -1\quad -1\\-1\qquad1\\\end{pmatrix}=2$

Since $\mathcal{P}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ where n=2=rank, $z$ is a corner of $\mathcal{P}$.

The polyhedron has two faces $F_1$ and $F_2$, which can be confirmed by sketching the two inequalities.
Intuitively, I would think that we could write $F_1$ and $F_2$ the following way:

$F_1=\mathcal{P}\cap\{(x_1,x_2):x_1+x_2\geq 1 \land x_1\geq 2\},\qquad$similarly:
$F_2=\mathcal{P}\cap\{(x_1,x_2):x_1-x_2\geq 3 \land x_1\geq 2\}$

The dimension of $F_1$  and $F_2$ is equal to $1$, as dim($F)=$dim$(\mathcal{P})-1=2-1=1$

Comment: "Polyhedron" is not usually the term used for a polygon, nor is "face" the usual term for a side. Leaving that aside, I agree with the vertex. But $F_1$ should be the points $(x_1,x_2)$ with $x_1+x_2=2$ and $x_1\ge2$. Similarly for $F_2$.

Comment: @almagest Thank you for the comment! Could you explain how you came up with $F_1$ and $F_2$? Also I used "polyhedron" and "face" because a polygon is just a flat polyhedron but you are of course right, that it is not actually a polyhedron.

Comment: Your $F_1$ would be fine if you replaced $x_1+x_2\ge1$ with $x_1+x_2=1$. At the moment it describes a 2-dimensional area. Ah! I see your point. My comment also had a typo: I put =2 instead of =1. Sorry!

Comment: @almagest Yes youre right. Thank you very much for the help. Does this mean that the correct answer is:  
$F_1=\mathcal{P}\cap\{(x_1,x_2):x_1+x_2= 1 \land x_1\geq 2\}$
$F_2=\mathcal{P}\cap\{(x_1,x_2):x_1-x_2= 3 \land x_1\geq 2\}$ ?

Comment: Yes, with that change, I think your answer is fine (although I still prefer "side" to "face"!